# How to use Idapython to add custom pop-up hints on operands in IDA Pro?

Tags: python, ida

In IDA Pro, by default, for some operands like destination addresses / jump targets, when my mouse cursor hovers around it, a pop-up box will appear and give a preview of the instructions in those destination program addresses.

I want to do the same thing for other operands, such as for registers that I want to give some contextual information in a pop-up box to help analysis. For example, in this function, what are the possible values this register can take due to earlier initialization etc. I will only need this pop up box will only show textual information.

Does IDAPython have something to allow me to do add 'hints' or such pop-up boxes? Does it allow me to replace or append the existing pop-up boxes for destination addresses?

the closest i found is UI_Hooks (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi.UI_Hooks-class.html) and (http://www.hexblog.com/?p=886). But I cannot find any examples to help me on that. Ideas, anyone?